# Why does ~/.local/share contain so many kinds of data?

Tags: files, design, localrepository

`~/.local/share` seems to be a collection of essential data, configuration data, log files, accumulated junk, and who knows what else.

Given that `~/.local` is already divided into `bin` and `lib`, why was a single directory created to contain everything else rather than creating several directories with more useful and natural categorizations?

For instance, why not have a directory for such things as:

- logs and other data that can safely be removed without affecting anything.
- user-specific configuration whose removal will affect behaviour but not break anything.
- essential data that software relies on (but isn't that what `.local/lib` is for?).

As it is, there's no obvious way of determining what doesn't need to be backed up nor what can (and often should) be periodically cleaned up or deleted.

The `share` namespace contains names of specific packages (e.g. `rhythmbox`, `nautilus`), generic names (e.g. `fonts`, `icons`), and seeming duplicates (e.g. `app-info` and `applications`).

In many cases, it's not at all obvious which package is associated with each directory.  For instance, is `share/Trash` used by multiple packages; and whether it is or not, which package is responsible for cleaning out old trash?

Is `~/.local` a work in progress, or was it designed much better than it appears and package maintainers have ignored that design, or am I totally missing something that should be obvious?

The above questions are mostly rhetorical, to illustrate my general confusion between what I see and what I think was intended, and are not meant to solicit explicit answers.

I expect that most of the answers *can* be found elsewhere though.
Specifically, **what is the original design and intended use of `~/.local`, and where is this documented?**

Comment: There's a current fashion among some developers to use /usr/share, /usr/local/share, and ~/.local/share. Fashions come and go.

Answer (score 2):

A premise: you will find all over internet a lot of discussions about the Linux directory structure, and half of them are about "controversial" design decisions.
Some folder structures have lost their original meaning and a lit bit of confusion is still present nowaday (consider for example all the discussions about: "in which bin folder I put my binaries?")

What I can say shortly is that ".local" is the like a cousin for "/usr" folder (they have the same internal structure!) but with a different perspective: the /usr directory contains applications and files used by users (and not by the system, whose applications and files are located in other places) and that may need to be safe from system updates.

".local" is typically reserved for "locally installed" applications, meaning stuffs that you install by yourself, not stuff that came with your distro installation. Consider also that every user will have its .local folder with its specific files and configuration.

Example: the system icon themes are installed in /usr/share/icons. You can put your icons in /.local/share/icons. And same things for themes, fonts etc.

Personally, I don't think it's a mess if you think of it from this point of view.

Comment: I find `~/.local/share/applications` most useful for holding .desktop files.

Comment: Yes, I remember when `/var` was separated from `/usr`.  Back when disk was in short supply, it meant we could NFS mount the same `/usr` onto several machines at the same time.  But this `~/share` seems to have taken a step backward and undone that idea.

Comment: *".local" is typically reserved for "locally installed" applications, meaning stuffs that you install by yourself, not stuff that came with your distro installation.*.  Except that I just created a brand new account, and its `.local/share` already contains:
`app-info flatpak gnome-shell ibus-table keyrings recently-used.xbel sounds zeitgeist evolution gnome-settings-daemon gvfs-metadata icc nautilus session_migration-ubuntu xorg`.

Comment: `/usr/local` is for locally installed packages/software (for all the users on the local OS instance), `~/.local` is a similar directory for user-installed packages/software (installed by a regular user for her/him-self) and for user-related data of all the available software.